# Android PHP Login

Tags: php, android

I'm having some trouble in getting some code to work in android/php.As it is, if I hardcode the value in the php, it returns 1 so it's able to get that from the database. I think the problem is with the connection between android and the php file, but not sure exactly where.

Login.java

```
public class Login extends Activity {
 EditText etUsername;
 EditText etPassword;
 Button btnLogin;
Button btnCancel;

SharedPreferences preferences;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Editor edit = preferences.edit();
    edit.putString("uName", "guest");
    edit.putString("pWord", "guest");
    edit.putBoolean("loggedIn", false);
    edit.commit();
    etUsername = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    etPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_button);




 // get the button resource in the xml file and assign it to a local variable of type Button
    Button launch = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    // this is the action listener
    launch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {     
            public void onClick(View viewParam)
            {

                String sUserName = etUsername.getText().toString();
                String sPassword = etPassword.getText().toString();
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", sUserName));
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", sPassword));


                String response = null;
                try {
                response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/login.php", postParameters);  
                String res=response.toString();
                // res = res.trim();
                res= res.replaceAll("\\s+","");

                if(res.equals("1")){
                    String LoginMsg = "Logging in!\nUsername: " 
                            + sUserName + "\nPassword: " + sPassword;
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, LoginMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent MenuIntent = new Intent(Login.this,MainMenu.class);
                startActivity(MenuIntent);
                }
                else  
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Invalid Login", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                }
                 catch (Exception e) {

                    etUsername.setText(e.toString());

                }}
            });
}}
```

CustomHttpClient.java

```
public class CustomHttpClient {
/** The time it takes for our client to timeout */
public static final int HTTP_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000; // milliseconds

/** Single instance of our HttpClient */
private static HttpClient mHttpClient;

/**
 * Get our single instance of our HttpClient object.
 *
 * @return an HttpClient object with connection parameters set
 */
private static HttpClient getHttpClient() {
    if (mHttpClient == null) {
        mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        final HttpParams params = mHttpClient.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
    }
    return mHttpClient;
}

/**
 * Performs an HTTP Post request to the specified url with the
 * specified parameters.
 *
 * @param url The web address to post the request to
 * @param postParameters The parameters to send via the request
 * @return The result of the request
 * @throws Exception
 */
public static String executeHttpPost(String url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
        request.setEntity(formEntity);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();

        String result = sb.toString();
        return result;
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Performs an HTTP GET request to the specified url.
 *
 * @param url The web address to post the request to
 * @return The result of the request
 * @throws Exception
 */
public static String executeHttpGet(String url) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
        request.setURI(new URI(url));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String line = "";
        String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + NL);
        }
        in.close();

        String result = sb.toString();
        return result;
    } finally {
        if (in != null) {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

PHP code

```
<?PHP

    mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");


    $query = "SELECT * FROM login where username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to verify user because: " .mysql_error());

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
echo 1;
}
else
{
echo 0;
} 

?>
```

Comment: What's exactly the outcome? Is there any error log or why does your code "not work"?

Comment: It just says invalid login no matter what I type. If I put the details saved in the database into the php on the $username part, I get 1 printed back in the browser. In eclipse, I just get invalid login

Comment: So res does not equal "1". Did you debug your response string to see what's actually your server response?

Comment: Yup,I get 0 despite the correct details being in

Comment: Maybe adding $username = $_POST["username"]; and $password = $_POST["password"]; helps? I don't see any error on your java code.

Comment: Nope,that doesn't work. The only way it seems to work in both android and php, is when I have it so that username = the actual username and same with password. Obviously, that's not the best solution to it though.

Comment: Ok,it works now, and not exactly sure why

Comment: oh god I hope you don't let users enter $username and $password. If you do please look up SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

```
launch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
```

to

```
launch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()) maybe?
```